# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsfilemanager

So, using Swift 2.0, it looks like Apple are steering us towards using `NSURL` rather than `NSString` for paths.

I’m trying to ascertain whether a file exists in the user’s Documents directory in iOS, and I can’t quite piece it together.

If I use the following, Swift 2.0 complains that I shouldn’t use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, and that I should use URLs.

```
let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let dbPath = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent(“Whatever.sqlite”)
```

If I then get the URL, like so:

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Retrollect.sqlite”)
```

I then can’t call `NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath` to ascertain whether the file exists.

Is there an equivalent of `fileExistsAtPath()` for an `NSURL`, to look inside the user’s Documents directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, one of those "five seconds later" answers.

I can use `fileExistsAtPath(theURL.path)` to do this. Checking that the `path` is non-nil first, of course!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** version:

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)
```